# How to show Product details in paypal express checkout

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, express-checkout

I have implemented express checkout like this

// Render the PayPal button

paypal.Button.render({

```
// Set your environment

env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

// PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
// Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

client: {
    sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
    production: 'Aco85QiB9jk8Q3GdsidqKVCXuPAAVbnqm0agscHCL2-K2Lu2L6MxDU2AwTZa-ALMn_N0z-s2MXKJBxqJ'
},

// Set to 'Pay Now'

commit: true,

// Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

payment: function() {

    // Make a client-side call to the REST api to create the payment

    return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
        transactions: [
            {
                amount: { total: '<?php echo $cart->total(); ?>', currency: 'USD' }
            }
        ]
    });
},

// Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

    // Execute the payment

    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
        document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').innerText = 'Payment Complete!';
        window.location.href = 'cartaction.php?action=place0rder';
    });
}
```

}, '#paypal-button-container');

where $cart->total() is total payable amount of all products. it works totally fine.

But i want to display all products name price and description as shown in following image.

[When we click Amount it shows item details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoBs0.png)

But here in my case It just shows amount like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRPIK.png)

What should I add in the code to achieve this. Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like the REST API integration, you can actually use the same parameter. Below is my sample code for that part:

```html
transactions: [
 {
  amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' },
  item_list: {
   items: [
    {
    name: 'hat',
    description: 'Brown hat.',
    quantity: '1',
    price: '1.00',
    currency: 'USD'
    }
   ]
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm!! @habdulkarim